# Does "the experience of transition requires negotiation between sacrifice and opportunity" make sense logically?

Tags: logic, fallacies, semantics

I've thought about this statement enough to know it doesn't make logical sense, but I've not thought hard enough to determine *why* it doesn't make logical sense. The word 'and' conceptually links two non-mutually exclusive concepts of sacrifice and opportunity. Can somebody explain how the experience of transition ALWAYS requires negotiation between the facets of sacrifice and opportunity? One can exist without the other, so this will not always be true, will it? Because that is what seems to be implied by the statement.

Comment: You seldom want both sacrifice and opportunity. Another problem is "the experience of", but it's not quite in that league.

Comment: I read this as saying "Change requires some give and take."  *The experience of transition* is *to change*, while *negotiation between sacrifice and opportunity* is *give and take*.  It makes sense to me, even if the language is a bit flowery.

Comment: @NickR But that is invalid unless the 'and' is replaced with 'for'. The word 'and' conceptually links the two non-mutually exclusive concepts of sacrifice and opportunity, hence creating contradictory undefined conditions

Comment: @NickR Do you agree with me?

Comment: @fgreag I'm not sure that I understand your comment.  The conjunction "sacrifice and opportunity" is not a *condition*, but a *consequent*.  If one experiences transition, then one has to have negotiated between sacrifice and opportunity.  It may not be true in all applications - i.e., it is possible to experience change without any such negotiations - but it appears logically sound.

Comment: @NickR my bad, you are correct in that part as it really is a consequent. Can you explain to me how the experience of transition ALWAYS requires negotiation between the facets of sacrifice and opportunity as these are not mutually exclusive ie one can exist without the other, hence it will not always be true? Because that is what is implied by the statement.

Comment: @fgreag I agree.  The experience of transition does not *always* require such negotiations. For example, if I find a dollar in the street, I am richer (transition) but I have not necessarily undertaken any sacrifice.  I think you may be confusing *truth* with *logical sense*.  As a formal proposition, we might write :  C ->  (S&O) , where C is change, S is sacrifice, and O is opportunity.  This is a valid proposition.  However, it is possible to substitute particular values for C, S, and O that create an **instance** of the proposition which is false (or true).

Comment: @NickR: formal logic *notation* does not help. this is just an associative sentence. as stated it's nonsense, but it's not hard to see that instead of "negotiation between sacrifice and opportunity" the author meant to write "choosing sacrifice and opportunity over safety and no opportunity". he or she just found it too hard to express that clearly, in my experience usually because of clouded associative thinking. there is a negotiation involved in making the choice. and by association that word made its way into the sentence. it's all, well, just associative.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You're probably right.  It is often difficult to make logical sense of an informal statement.

Answer (score 1):

This question is essentially duplicated from English SE [Does this essay question make sense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252446/does-this-essay-question-make-sense), where the phrasing "*The process of changing into new social contexts requires compromise between sacrifice and opportunity*" provides additional context. Reference to social contexts implies that the "experience of transition" refers to change in social behavior of a person.

There is a difference between making sense and being true, "2 is an odd number" makes perfect sense, even if it is false. "Negotiation between sacrifice and opportunity" may or may not be necessary for engaging in social transition, but asserting that it is is a sensible statement. What is off about the OP sentence is the use of a passive noun "experience" (or "process") instead of an active one like "engagement", whereas "negotiation" implies conscious or at least willful participation. Presumably, one could experience a transition just happening to them without any active engagement, negotiated or otherwise. But even such interpretation would make the sentence false, not non-sensical. Of course, "negotiation between sacrifice and opportunity", read literally, involves communication between two abstract concepts, which is non-sensical, but such metaphorical frivolities are commonly used, e.g. in "struggles between passions and reason".

Summarizing, [the principle of charity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_charity) directs us to construe a text in a way most favorable to its being sensible and true, before doubting and criticizing. We could then assume that in the author's view even passively stated "experience of transition" requires person's action to occur, e.g. sacrificing old habits to new social opportunities, and imagine a psychological theory under which such action involves either conscious or subconscious "negotiation" of trade-offs between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Insofar as you are asking if it is sound logic, the answer is no.  One does not have to negotiate, or do anything, to experience transition.  Why?  Because unqualified transition may require no effort.

A fitting Machiavelli quote:
"It must be considered that there is nothing more difficult to carry out nor more doubtful of success nor more dangerous to handle than to initiate a new order of things; for the reformer has enemies in all those who profit by the old order, and only lukewarm defenders in all those who would profit by the new order; this lukewarmness arising partly from the incredulity of mankind who does not truly believe in anything new until they actually have experience of it."